# Displaying array data in table with react

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to display some data in a table using React.JS and Im having trouble understanding how to get it all to work. I can get the data to display using just a p tag but thats not what I want. I'm not sure where to go here since I am still reactjs is still new to me I have looked through numerous tutorials and have tried a few different things to see if something would display but nothing has happened.

````
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, {useMemo, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Table from 'react';

function App() {

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  // const columns = useMemo(() => [
  //   {
  //     Header: "Population Density",
  //     accessor: "DENSITY_2021",
  //   },
  //   {
  //     Header: "Population",
  //     accessor: "POP_2021",
  //   },
  //   {
  //     Header: "State",
  //     accessor: "NAME",
  //   },
  // ])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.census.gov/data/2021/pep/population?get=DENSITY_2021,POP_2021,NAME,STATE&for=state:*")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {

    return(
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Population Density</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>State</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        console.log(items)
        </tbody>
      </table>
  );}```

I have tried displaying to get the data to display by using
````

````
      {items.map(item => {
        return (
          <tr key={item.DENSITY_2021}>
            <td>{ item.POP_2021}</td>
            <td>{ item.NAME }</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}```
````

in the table body

Answer (score 0):

you imported the wrong component

Change `import Table from 'react';` to `import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';`

make sure you have installed the react-bootstrap

to install a react-bootstrap with bootstrap or you can follow this https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

`npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap --save`

or

`yarn install react-bootstrap bootstrap --save`

here is the updated version.

```
<table>
   <head>
     <tr>
       <th>Density</th>
       <th>Population</th>
       <th>State</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>

    <tbody>
        {items.map(item => {
         <tr key={item.STATE}>
           <td>{item.DENSITY_2021}</td>
           <td>{item.POP_2021}</td>
           <td>{item.NAME}</td>
        </tr>

         })}
      </tbody>
</table>
```

or you can use

```
<tbody>
  {items.map(item => (
    <tr key={item.STATE}>
      <td>{item.DENSITY_2021}</td>
      <td>{item.POP_2021}</td>
      <td>{item.NAME}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply unfortunately when I go to save it I am still only getting the table heading